# Three.js particles and scroll handling

Tags: javascript, three.js

So, I've been experimenting with three.js to create a particle background width parallax effect on scroll. But I'm stuck on how to connect the dots with lines and handling the scroll parallax effect (not as smooth as [EPFL site](https://rapport-annuel.epfl.ch/en/2018/)).

And the movement of the dots are similar (going to the right side, instead of random direction).

This is what I've done so far:

```js
var scene, camera, renderer, controls;
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

// particles set up
var particleCount = 200;
// var move_speed = new THREE.Vector3(0.3, 0.5, 0);
var move_delta = 0.2;
var scroll_delta_factor = 0.05;
var scroll_delta = 0;
var max_size = 6;
var particles = [];
var sdri = null;

init();
animate();

function init() {
  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  // camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
  camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(window.innerWidth / -2, window.innerWidth / 2, window.innerHeight / 2, window.innerHeight / -2, 1, 10000);
  camera.position.z = 1000;

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setClearColor(0x0E171B, 1);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

  // controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
  // controls.enableDamping = true;
  // controls.dampingFactor = 0.25;
  // controls.enableZoom = false;

  fillScene();

  canvas.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);

  window.addEventListener('wheel', onMouseWheel, {
    passive: false
  });
}

function onMouseWheel(evt) {
  event.preventDefault();

  // camera.position.y -= event.deltaY * 0.005;

  // prevent scrolling beyond a min/max value
  // camera.position.clampScalar( 0, 10 );
  scroll_delta = evt.deltaY;
}

function fillScene() {
  var particleMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0xFFFFFF,
    transparent: true,
    opacity: 0.5
  });

  // create a random set of particles
  for (var i = 0; i < particleCount; i++) {
    var size = Math.max(Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max_size)), 1);
    var particleGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(size, 32, 32); // size, number of polys to form this circle
    particles[i] = new THREE.Mesh(particleGeometry, particleMaterial);

    //randomize positions
    particles[i].position.x = Math.random() * window.innerWidth * 2 - window.innerWidth;;
    particles[i].position.y = Math.random() * window.innerHeight * 2 - window.innerHeight;
    // particles[i].position.z = Math.random() * window.innerWidth * 2 - window.innerWidth;
    // particles[i].position.z = 1;

    particles[i].direction = {
      x: Math.random(),
      y: Math.random()
    }

    scene.add(particles[i]);
  }
}

function resetScrollDelta() {
  if (scroll_delta > 0)
    scroll_delta = Math.max(0, scroll_delta -= (0.2 + scroll_delta_factor));
  else if (scroll_delta < 0)
    scroll_delta = Math.min(0, scroll_delta += (0.2 + scroll_delta_factor));
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  // controls.update();

  for (var i = 0; i < particleCount; i++) {
    // particles[i].position.x += (particles[i].direction.x * move_speed);
    // particles[i].position.y += (particles[i].direction.y * move_speed);
    particles[i].position.add(new THREE.Vector3(
      particles[i].direction.x * move_delta,
      particles[i].direction.y * move_delta * (scroll_delta * scroll_delta_factor),
      0));

    // setTimeout(() => {
    //     scroll_delta = Math.max(0, scroll_delta -= scroll_delta_factor);
    // }, 500);

    // if edge is reached, bounce back
    if (particles[i].position.x < -window.innerWidth || particles[i].position.x > window.innerWidth) {
      particles[i].direction.x = -(particles[i].direction.x * move_delta);
    }
    if (particles[i].position.y < -window.innerHeight || particles[i].position.y > window.innerHeight) {
      particles[i].direction.y = -(particles[i].direction.y * move_delta);
    }
  }

  if (scroll_delta !== 0)
    sdri = setInterval(() => {
      console.log('reset scroll delta', scroll_delta)
      resetScrollDelta();
    }, 500);
  else if (sdri) {
    console.log('clear interval')
    clearInterval(sdri);
    sdri = null;
  }

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Three.js</title>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    canvas {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="canvas"></div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/110/three.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

*PS: I'm not a JavaScript or three.js expert, and numeric calculations is a pain, so please bear with me*

*Disclaimer: The code I used is just an edited version of what I found while searching*

Comment: If you want to connect the dots with lines, you should look at the code [in this  example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=draw#webgl_buffergeometry_drawrange) , it does exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Ohhhh.. thank you @Marquizzo. I don't know why I didn't see this example.